# Iterate through and conditionally append string values in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, dplyr, iteration

I've got a dataframe of research participants whose IDs are stored in the following format "0000.000". 
Where the first four digits are their family ID number, and the final three digits are their individual index within the family. The majority of individuals have a suffix of ".000", but some have ".001", ".002", etc.

As a result of some inefficiencies, these numbers are stored as floats. I'm trying to import them as strings so that I can use them in a join to another data frame that is formatted correctly.

Those IDs that end in .000 are imported as "0000", rather than "0000.000". All others are imported correctly.

I'm trying to iterate through the IDs and append ".000" to those that are missing the suffix.

If I were using R, I could do it like this.

```
df %>% mutate(StudyID = ifelse(length(StudyID)<5,
                               paste(StudyID,".000",sep=""),
                               StudyID)
```

I've found a Python solution (below), but it's pretty janky.

```
row = 0
for i in df["StudyID"]:
    if len(i)<5:
        df.iloc[row,3] = i + ".000"
    else: df.iloc[row,3] = i
    index += 1
```

I think it'd be ideal to do it as a list comprehension, but I haven't been able to find a solution that lets me iterate through the column, changing a single value at a time.

For example, this solution iterates and checks the logic properly, but it replaces every single value that evaluates True during each iteration. I only want the value currently being evaluated to change.

```
[i + ".000" if len(i)<5 else i for i in df["StudyID"]]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't you want to change every value that evaluates as true? In which cases would you want to not append `".000"`?

Comment: That's right, I only want the values shorter than 5 characters to be appended.

The IDs that have ".001" or higher don't need to be appended because they've been imported correctly and are 8 characters long. 

Only the short IDs need to be appended.

Comment: So what's the problem? It looks like your code does what you want

Comment: I think in `R`, the syntax is wrong If you are checking for the number of characters, it should be `nchar(StudyID) < 5` instead of `length(StudyID) < 5`

Comment: My code does what I want, but I want to know if there's a more concise way of doing it. Specifically with list comprehension.

@akrun, yeah I wasn't sure about that. I don't have access to R on this computer (otherwise I'd be using it) so I couldn't test the dplyr solution.

Comment: Again, you have written a list comprehension. It does what you want. It is concise. What is the problem? What is your question? There is nothing to solve here.

Comment: The list comprehension doesn't solve the problem. It iterates through the dataframe and applies the logical evaluation correctly. However, each time it evaluates to true, it replaces every single value that evaluates to True. What I want is for each true iteration, replace the current value with the current value *plus* ".000"

Comment: @James we have a loop. Please see my first comment. Don't you want to change every value that evaluates as true? In which cases would you not want to append `".000"`?

Comment: @DeNovo I think we're miscommunicating. I've found a better solution that iteratively splits the string on the full-stop and appends a "000" to for those resulting lists that only have one element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ultimately, I needed to do this for a few different dataframes so I ended up defining a function to solve the problem so that I could apply it to each one.

I think the list comprehension idea was going to become too complex and potentially too difficult to understand when reviewing so I stuck with a plain old for-loop.

```
def create_multi_index(data, col_to_split, sep = "."):
    """
    This function loops through the original ID column and splits it into 
        multiple parts (multi-IDs) on the defined separator.
        By default, the function assumes the unique ID is formatted like a decimal number
    The new multi-IDs are appended into a new list. 
        If the original ID was formatted like an integer, rather than a decimal
            the function assumes the latter half of the ID to be ".000"
    """    

    # Take a copy of the dataframe to modify
    new_df = data

    # generate two new lists to store the new multi-index
    Family_ID = []
    Family_Index = []

    # iterate through the IDs, split and allocate the pieces to the appropriate list
    for i in new_df[col_to_split]:

        i = i.split(sep)

        Family_ID.append(i[0])

        if len(i)==1:
            Family_Index.append("000")
        else: 
            Family_Index.append(i[1])

    # Modify and return the dataframe including the new multi-index
    return new_df.assign(Family_ID = Family_ID,
                         Family_Index = Family_Index)
```

This returns a duplicate dataframe with a new column for each part of the multi-id.

When joining dataframes with this form of ID, as long as both dataframes have the multi index in the same format, these columns can be used with pd.merge as follows:

`pd.merge(df1, df2, how= "inner", on = ["Family_ID","Family_Index"])`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your code is doing the trick. One other way of doing what you want that i could think of is the following :

```
# Start by creating a mask that gives you the index you want to change
mask = [len(i)<5 for i in df.StudyID]
# Change the value of the dataframe on the mask
df.StudyID.iloc[mask] += ".000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by `length(StudyID)`, you meant `nchar(StudyID)`, as @akrun pointed out.

You can do it in the `dplyr` way in python using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, mutate, nchar, if_else, paste
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     StudyID = ["0000", "0001", "0000.000", "0001.001"]
... )
>>> df
    StudyID
   <object>
0      0000
1      0001
2  0000.000
3  0001.001
>>> 
>>> df >> mutate(StudyID=if_else(
...   nchar(f.StudyID) < 5,
...   paste(f.StudyID, ".000", sep=""), 
...   f.StudyID
... ))
    StudyID
   <object>
0  0000.000
1  0001.000
2  0000.000
3  0001.001
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.